# Azure APIM Policy, managed identity resource value from namevalue

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I am trying to render managed identity resource value from name value
This is in my code and deployment happens via the terraform.

values I have in name value are

[image]

I tried

```
<authentication-managed-identity resource="{{CRM-EWR-Resource-Client-Id}}" />
```

after deployment it is rendered as

```
<authentication-managed-identity resource="{{CRM-EWR-Resource-Client-Id}}" />
```

Then I tried

```
<authentication-managed-identity resource="CRM-EWR-Resource-Client-Id" />
```

after deployment it is rendered as

```
<authentication-managed-identity resource="CRM-EWR-Resource-Client-Id" />
```

It should render like this

```
<authentication-managed-identity resource="de08357d-b6c-454-wew-21321sd" />
```

**Update**
This worked

```
<set-variable name="test" value="{{CRM-EWR-Resource-Client-Id_dev}}" />
    <authentication-managed-identity resource="@(context.Variables["test"] as string)" />
```

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please post the solution as answer to help the community

Answer (score 0):

Following worked.

```
<set-variable name="test" value="{{CRM-EWR-Resource-Client-Id_dev}}" />
<authentication-managed-identity resource="@(context.Variables["test"] as string)" />
```